# Best way to store PC application data localy and sync with server database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Please, i have a question.

What is optimal way to store some settings and application data like tables or products info of my application localy. That means, data of my program is store on computer where application running.
But, If I want to use or work on this app on other computer it is problem because there aren´t same settings and data. So, I want to work on this app locally on my computer without internet. But, i want to synchoronizing tables and data with other computer if i want to.

I want to develop my personal application on desktop computer. It is like economical applicaton where are lots of products and peoples tables. I choose VS2015 C#.

Thank you very much for any reply.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: Also, you know that Visual Studio 2019 is available, and free, right? You should consider using the newest tools whenever possible.

Comment: what advantages of using VS2019 instead VS2015 brings to me? I think i am not able to use all features of whole IDE. And newer versions have more requirements on PC.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely and that makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions.

Comment: Visual Studio Express isn't that resource intensive. Any machine made in the last ten years should be able to handle it, unless you're on some really tight build with less than 4GB of memory. 8GB is ideal. 16GB is optimal. If you're really strapped for performance and want a cheap boost, replacing an HDD with an SSD can give a literal 10x improvement, and SSD prices have never been lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that’s very popular right now is to use SQLite, which leverages the power of sql while being easily contained within your local file system.  It’s a popular option used in both desktop and mobile applications currently.

https://www.sqlite.org/index.html  - Project site
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki  - ADO.net providers.

Another option is to simply serialize collections of objects and write them to a file.    You can then use LINQ (Language Integrated Query), to manage and select the data within your application as desired.   However, SQLite would be my first choice.

I would also suggest upgrading to visual studio 2019 unless there are limitations within your system that prevent it.  VS2019 is more widely supported by the latest library’s and 3rd party solutions.  Many of the newer versions of DotNet, like DotNet Core, will not be supported in VS2015 (Though .net core 2.0 is supported in the 2017 version).

Comment: I took your advice and read more about VS 2019. It is true that many features like intelisense and code suggestions and cleanup is on higer level. So iconsider to install and try VS2019.

Comment: I considering the possibility to use SQLite. But, how about sync local SQLite database with DB server on internet and again back to SQLite?

Comment: SQLite doesn't do concurrency to well, it also falls short on stored procedures.  Both would be nice if you want to scale up.  So if you need to serve multiple clients concurrently SQLite might not be the path you want.  Also, I’m not a big fan of exposing any database directly to the internet.  I would use a restful webservice to expose those resources.   The link below details how to set one up with DotNet Core.  You can consume that webservices using the HttpClient class.

Comment: It’s hard to know what you don’t know, so for reference:
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/35462/creating-web-api-in-asp-net-core-2-0/part-1---web-api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I also realize that sometimes you simply need to access the data server remotely, or you are going to need to handle concurrency issues.  In those cases you have one more reason NOT to use SQLite as your server.   SQL Server Express by Microsoft will work nicely up to about 10GB of data, then you need to pay.   When you need to scale up, investigate some of the Azure data packages.  They charge by units of data used (which they have never been quite clear on).  If you are a cheapskate like me, and fancy yourself competent with Linux, you can always give Postgresql a shot.

Comment: For further reference, when you need to secure your web service, look into JWT or bearer tokens.